# Hide permission groups in SharePoint

Tags: permissions

Is there a way to hide permission groups in SharePoint. We are having to programatically create permission a group in SharePoint, but we would not want the end users to add to this permission group. Can this be accomplished?

Navin

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can hide the groups, but you can set a service account as owner and specify that only the owner can add members (AllowMembersEditMembership = false)

Answer (score 1):

As long as the users don't have full control, they won't be able to manage permissions and therefore set your permission level.  This may or may not be a possibility depending on how the site is managed.