# Is it possible to update/set SPGroup IsHiddenInUI?

Tags: groups, spprincipal

On SPGroup there is a property called [IsHiddenInUI](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.spprincipal.ishiddeninui.aspx) - *a value that indicates whether this member should be hidden in the UI*. However you can't set that (it is a *get* only).

I'm creating some groups I want to be hidden if possible, and this looks like the option I want to set, only it is not possible.

Question is how I get around that - am I missing some special creation parameter or is it possible to specify somehow else?

Answer (score 1):

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spprincipal.ishiddeninui.aspx) it's a `getter` property, so you can not set it.

A [similar question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/36934/2536) was asked a few years back. However according to the answer:

> you can set a service account as owner and specify that only the owner
>   can add members (AllowMembersEditMembership = false)

if that is why you're asking.

Comment: I know that - the reason I'm asking is that I've earlier seen examples of changing value of "getter only" properties via XML. Perhaps something similar can be done here.

Comment: You could try using reflection in C# to set it. I'm not familiar with any other approach.